# Переменная не записывается в базу данных php

Tags: php, sql, url

Всем привет, у меня есть переменная взятая из url, и она не записывается в базу данных, но если её просмотреть через var_dump, то вся информация есть, также если её вывести через echo то всё выводится, но столбец базы данных, в которого записывают переменную, пустой. Помогите пожалуйста.
Вот код:

```
'''
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-/xUj+3OJU5yExlq6GSYGSHk7tPXikynS7ogEvDej/m4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<?php
    include 'index.html';
    include 'rb.php';
    $connect = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=u1724412_default; charset=UTF8", '*', '*');
    if (isset($_POST['comment'])){
        $comment = $_POST['comment'];
        $username = $_GET['username'];
        $date = date('H:i:s');
        $query = $connect->query("INSERT INTO u1724412_default.comments (username, comment, data) VALUES ('$username', '$comment', '$date')");
    }
    echo gettype($username);
    var_dump($username);
?>

<?
    $comments = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM *.comments ORDER BY data DESC");
    $comments = $comments->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
<div class="scroll-block"></div>
<?
    if ($comments){
        foreach($comments as $comment){
?>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="block">
            <div class="username"><?=$comment['username']?></div>
            <br>
            <div class="comment"><?=$comment['comment']?></div>
            <div class="data"><?=$comment['data']?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?
'''
```

Comment: `H:i:s` - это не дата.....это время........... также возможно не data, а date?

Comment: выведи ошибки на страницу, посмотр что пишет

Comment: Ошибку не выводит, просто пустой столбец

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: Вот ошибка: 
Notice: Undefined variable: username in /var/www/u1724412/data/www/forum-dvoryashin.ru/index.php on line 28

Comment: попробуй так `\`username\`, \`comment\`, \`data\``

Comment: Ничего не меняется, ошибка осталась

Comment: ааа... ну понятно.... если в `if (isset($_POST['comment'])){`  не заходит, то и `echo gettype($username);
    var_dump($username);`  будет выдавать ошибку

Comment: А что делать, чтобы записалась переменная в бд?

Comment: надо её передать в код ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯    воспользуйся отладкой, может быть что-то у тебя не прилетает.......... с учётом того, что у тебя одновременно POST и GET.......

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите логи веб сервера.

Возможно у вас проблемы на этапе обращения к БД.
И тогда в логах ошибок вы это увидите.

Так же можно посоветовать проверить настройки подключения через PDO.

Подключиться и прочитать то что есть в БД получается?

Возможно не соответствует тип даты в php и в БД, а т.к. вы не обрабатываете в коде ошибки БД, то смотреть опять же лог ошибок. Можно проверить запись комментария без даты.

Так же PDO хорош "подготовленными (prepared)" выражениями. В текущем виде реализация закладывает в код уязвимость типа SQL-injection. Если код не учебный а боевой - рекомендую проработать этот аспект.

p.s. Кстати, можно вывод ошибок в php настроить (как вам советовал коллега выше), например добавив в шапку php файла

```php
<?php 
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set("display_errors", 1);
?>
```

**UP:**

вы используете jquery ajax, и отправляете комментарий и имя пользователя методом POST, а в бэкэнд части, имя пользователя берёте из массива $_GET. Это сработало бы, если бы вы указали например

```html
 <form action="/index.php?username=Vasya" method="POST">
```

и отправляли бы через submit, в текущем варианте можно попробовать изменить строчку в ajax

```js
url: "index.php",
```

на

```js
url: "index.php?username="+username,
```

И раскомментировать инпут для имени пользователя

Вот только не уверен что это хорошая практика.

p.s.: Если бы сразу приложили код страницы, мы бы меньше "гадали" что там у вас за бага

[image: ScreenShot]

[Полезная информация здесь](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages)

Comment: Нет, все данные в бд записываются кроме одной переменной полученной из url

Comment: поправил ответ выше - добавил скриншот

Comment: А с помощью ajax можно передать данные на другой домен?

Comment: [ссылка на обсуждение схожей темы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript) и [там же, вариант ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298745/how-do-i-send-a-cross-domain-post-request-via-javascript/7605119#7605119)